# ¿ Cómo devolver el resultado de un json en un web panel en genexus 16?

Tags: java, json, genexus

Tengo un web panel que contiene dos variables username y clave y al hacer clik en el boton confirmar genera un token desde un web service mediante un procedimiento que invoca a otro procedimiento el problema que estoy teniendo es que no se como mostrar los resultados de la respuesta json en la web panel

> mi web panel contiene este codigo en la parte de eventos el boton confirmar llama al primer procedimiento, cree dos variables globales(dominios) username y password para utilizarlos como parámetros

Sub 'U_Confirmar'

```
     Eautenticacion.Call(&Username, &clave)
```

EndSub

> En este procedimiento cree un sdt con dos variables para poder enviar los parametros como json desde aqui tambien invoco a la api
>
> Rules ====== parm(&Username, &clave);

```
msg('=======================================================================',status)
```

&SDTauthenticate.Username = &Username

&SDTauthenticate.clave = &clave

&body = &SDTauthenticate.ToJson()

msg('Body...',status)

msg(&body,status)

msg('Invoco servicio REST authenticate',status)

RESTauthenticate.Call('http://midominio/api','POST',&body,&httpstatus,&result,'content-type','application/json')

> Y aqui en este procedimiento mediante httpclient puedo generar los resultados de la llamada a la api
>
> Rules=parm(&getstring,&method,&addstring,out:&httpstatus,out:&result,&headername,&headervalue);

```
msg('Getstring:'+&getstring,status)

msg('Method:'+&method,status)

if not &addstring.IsEmpty()

    &httpclient.AddString(&addstring)

endif

if not &headername.IsEmpty() and not &headervalue.IsEmpty()

    &httpclient.AddHeader(&headername,&headervalue)

endif

&httpclient.Execute(&method,&getstring) 

&httpstatus = &httpclient.StatusCode

msg('Http status: ' + &httpstatus,status)

&result = &httpclient.ToString()

msg('Output: ',status)

msg(&result,status)

msg('=========',status)
```

Answer (score 1):

Para mostrar el resultado del llamado http, podes hacer un "fromJson()" del resultado de tu request, es decir:

```
&SDTResultado.FromJson(&result)
```

y luego mostras en el webpanel el SDT. Eso te sirve? o tal vez no entendi bien tu pregunta.

Te recomiendo que leas este documento que seguro te va a ayudar:

https://wiki.genexus.com/commwiki/servlet/wiki?22574,Json%202%20SDT

Comment: He puesto este codigo &SDTauthenticate.FromJson(&result) en el web panel bajo el boton Sub 'U_Confirmar' pero no devuelve los resultados, bueno es la primera vez que lo estoy consumiendo desde genexus y no tengo mucho conocimiento

Comment: Pero el sub 'U_Confirmar' no esta recibiendo el json, cierto? Eautenticacion.Call(&Username, &clave) por lo que veo ahi, solo envias usuario y clave, pero no retornas el valor del json que trae el servicio.

Comment: Te sugiero mires este video: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=acEKsINmAv4&ab_channel=Soft%26DevTips

Comment: Gracias ya logre solucionarlo devolviendo los parametros en un sdt bajo el boton 'U_Confirmar' de esta manera Eautenticacion.Call(&Username,&clave, &Apiresponse)  &Datos_Output = &ApiResponse.ToJson()